# US visa application in the UK

Tags: b1-b2-visas, applications

Can international students in UK apply for US visa in the UK? I have been refused a US tourist visa before in my home country.  But I have travelled in and out of the UK. I have been to the Netherlands, France, Czech Republic, Hungary and Germany.

I am currently doing my masters in the UK.  I want to apply for a US visa while in the UK.  But I'm skeptical.  Would they expect that I apply from my home country? Or I can go ahead and apply in the UK?

Comment: You may want to do some research about reasons for refusal so you can reduce the possibility that your next application will also be refused.

Comment: I would do that. Thank you very much

Answer (score 4):

You can apply in the UK:

> Nonimmigrant visas are processed at the U.S. Embassy in London or the Consulate General in Belfast. If you are in the United Kingdom, you may schedule an appointment to apply for a visa at either post regardless of your nationality or status in the United Kingdom. — [U.S. Embassy in London](https://uk.usembassy.gov/visas/tourism-visitor/where-to-apply/)